# How to de-aggregate binomial response data from individuals with the same covariates to bernoulli and vice-versa?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, data.table, tidyverse

I want to implement binary logistic regression using binomial data as discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144121/logistic-regression-bernoulli-vs-binomial-response-variables). Additionally, I want to add a variable that identifies each binary data point coming from de-aggregation of the same binomial data point, so that I can properly account for their correlation in the analysis.

Below I present the outcome of my attempts so far. It successfully replicates the rows with respective covariates, but does not generate the binary variable yet. Any help would be much appreciated.

**#Structure of input binomial data#**

```
DT<-tibble::tibble(Successes = c(2,3,3), Trials=c(3,4,5), X1=c("Yes", "No", "Yes"), X2=c(10.7, 11.3, 9.9))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Successes Trials X1       X2
      <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
         2      3 Yes    10.7
         3      4 No     11.3
         3      5 Yes     9.9
```

**#My attempts so far#**

```
DT.expanded <- DT[rep(seq(nrow(DT)), DT$Trials), ]

DT.expanded
# A tibble: 12 x 4
   Successes Trials X1       X2
       <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
          2      3 Yes    10.7
          2      3 Yes    10.7
          2      3 Yes    10.7
          3      4 No     11.3
          3      4 No     11.3
          3      4 No     11.3
          3      4 No     11.3
          3      5 Yes     9.9
          3      5 Yes     9.9
          3      5 Yes     9.9
          3      5 Yes     9.9
          3      5 Yes     9.9
```

**#Expected structure of output binary data#**

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
    Success   X1       X2
       <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
         1    Yes    10.7
         1    Yes    10.7
         0    Yes    10.7
         1    No     11.3
         1    No     11.3
         1    No     11.3
         0    No     11.3
         1    Yes     9.9
         1    Yes     9.9
         1    Yes     9.9
         0    Yes     9.9
         0    Yes     9.9
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: We are not here to write code. That's what we do at work to get paid. Try something, even if it is rudimentary and then we can help you to reach your goal. **We are here to help**

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for posting soon the question. I am still editing it. I will soon update and post the outcome of my attempts so far.

Comment: also: change that image for actual copy-pastable code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this sort of expansion, I find it's easiest to generate a list column, where the list element for each row is a binary vector for that row, which you can create with `c` and `rep` for the appropriate number of 0s and 1s. Once you've got a list column, you can expand the data frame to fit. For example,

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
    Successes = c(2,3,3), 
    Trials = c(3,4,5), 
    X1 = c("Yes", "No", "Yes"), 
    X2 = c(10.7, 11.3, 9.9)
)

df <- df %>% mutate(binary = map2(Successes, Trials, 
                                  ~ c(rep(1, .x), 
                                      rep(0, .y - .x))))
df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   Successes Trials X1       X2 binary   
#>       <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <list>   
#> 1         2      3 Yes    10.7 <dbl [3]>
#> 2         3      4 No     11.3 <dbl [4]>
#> 3         3      5 Yes     9.9 <dbl [5]>

df2 <- df %>% unnest()
df2
#> # A tibble: 12 x 5
#>    Successes Trials X1       X2 binary
#>        <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1         2      3 Yes    10.7      1
#>  2         2      3 Yes    10.7      1
#>  3         2      3 Yes    10.7      0
#>  4         3      4 No     11.3      1
#>  5         3      4 No     11.3      1
#>  6         3      4 No     11.3      1
#>  7         3      4 No     11.3      0
#>  8         3      5 Yes     9.9      1
#>  9         3      5 Yes     9.9      1
#> 10         3      5 Yes     9.9      1
#> 11         3      5 Yes     9.9      0
#> 12         3      5 Yes     9.9      0
```

Answer (score 2):

An approach using `data.table` and `replace`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)
DT[, .(Success=replace(rep(0L, Trials), seq_len(Successes), 1L), 
       X1, X2), 
    by=seq_len(DT[,.N])][, -1L]
```

output:

```
    Success  X1   X2
 1:       1 Yes 10.7
 2:       1 Yes 10.7
 3:       0 Yes 10.7
 4:       1  No 11.3
 5:       1  No 11.3
 6:       1  No 11.3
 7:       0  No 11.3
 8:       1 Yes  9.9
 9:       1 Yes  9.9
10:       1 Yes  9.9
11:       0 Yes  9.9
12:       0 Yes  9.9
```